# An analogous in $\mathbb R[x]$ of the property $p=a^2+b^2$ in $\mathbb N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

It is known that all prime number $p\space (>0)$ of the form $4n+1$ is a sum of two squares of integers $a, b \ge 0$. Prove the following analogous property for positive polynomials in $\mathbb R[x]$:
$$P\ge 0\iff \exists\space S,T\in\mathbb R[x]\space   \text {such that}\space P= S^2+T^2$$
HINT.- Remember that the set $S={\{a^2+b^2};\space a,b \in{\mathbb N}$} 
 is a multiplicative monoid;$\space$ i.e. closed under multiplication.

Comment: What does $P\geq 0$ mean in $\mathbb R[x]$? Does it mean $P(\alpha)\geq 0$ for all  $\alpha\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Sharing your efforts allows other users to help you in a more suitable way, and makes them more inclined to help to begin with.

Comment: Do you know that all real polynomials factor into linear and quadratic real polynomials? That is, that $\mathbb R[x]$ is a unique factorization domain and the primes are all linear and quadratic?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: $P(x)\ge 0$ for all real $x$. The first zero above is the polynomial (not a number) defined by $P(x)=0$ for all x.

Comment: I strongly warn against using $x$ for a real value when $x$ is the indeterminate of $\mathbb R[x]$. That will confuse you in the long run. The $x$ in $\mathbb R[x]$ is not a real number, and should never be treated also as a variable. (Hence, my use of $\alpha$, to make absolutely clear that $\alpha$ is something completely different from $x$.) @Ataulfo

Comment: @Servaes: This problem, without given solution, appears on a French page.

Comment: The extension of this problem to several variables is hard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_SOS.

Comment: @lhf: A very good source for your problem, (if you do not  know it), is truly: Paulo Ribenboim's book "L'Arithmétique des Corps," Chapter 10. Sure there are translation into English.

Answer (score 3):

**Outline**

We can assume $P$ is monic. This is not entirely trivial, because you have to show that the first coefficient of $P$ can't be negative. (If it were, then it wouldn't be true that $P\geq 0$.)

Now, factor $P$ into primes. All primes in $\mathbb R[x]$ are of the form $x+r$ for real $r$ or quadratics of the form $x^2+ax+b$ where $a^2<4b$ (so the roots are complex.)

We can assume that $P$ is square-free, because if $P=P_1^2P_2$ then a solution for $P_2=X^2+Y^2$ easily yields a solution $P=(P_1X)^2+(P_1Y)^2$.

If $P$ is square-free and positive, then show that it cannot have any linear divisors $x-r$. (That's the big step.) So $P$ must be a product of quadratic primes.

Then show that $x^2+ax+b=X^2+Y^2$ can be solved when $a^2<4b$. Hint: Complete the square.

Finally, apply the hint, showing that if $P=X_1^2+Y_1^2$ and $Q=X_2^2+Y_2^2$ then you can find a solution to $PQ=X^2+Y^2$. This doesn't follow from the same fact about $\mathbb N$, but it is easily proven the same way (and it is easily proven in any commutative ring.)

Comment: Why "big step" ?: $ f (x) = ax + b $ is always negative for $x\lt \frac {-b}{a}$ when $a\gt 0$.
With great respect, leave strive those who does not know much, either completely explicit your solution,please, for young people who are learning.). (By the way, I have met a number among the greatest “connaisseurs”, who can not solve Olympic problems for beardless students…). Sincerely yours.

Comment: @Ataulfo Sure, but you have to show that there is no way for $(ax+b)(cx+d)$ to always be positive if it is square-free. You need to show that if $P$ is positive, all its square-free factors are positive. But see, you missed the big step, even when I told you it was a big step.

Comment: As for how one should answer here, please do not tell people who have been here for years and answered close to 2000 questions how to answer, in general. If you want a specific type of answer, that is fine. I gave an outline because I want to help.But lecturing me "with great respect" about how to answer in general is insulting and ridiculous.

Comment: Apparently you are not entirely in favor of freedom of thought. In any case, my intention was not to be insulting and ridiculous. I do not share your pride in anything (our existential positions are very different) but I understand you. Some time ago gave up the idea  of considering me infallible (it started when a great mathematician convinced me that mathematics are not the truth but a logical game, but that's another story). I see this time I failed again. My apologies.

Comment: I didn't say you are not allowed to be a jerk. I said please don't be a jerk. And you continue to be so. "Freedom of thought?" People who complain about "freedom of thought" usually don't have many. @Ataulfo "I didn't mean to be insulting" **right after deliberately insulting me.** You are a slippery one.

Comment: Very funny indeed. I do not want to insult you in any way but you complain that I insult though is you who evidently insults. I no longer answer. With much respect and consideration, good luck. Sincerely yours.

Comment: @Ataulfo Yeah, right, you never meant to insult when you said, "Apparently you are not entirely in favor of freedom of thought." Nor did you intend to insult when you lectured me in general about how to be a good answerer. You are just a naturally rude person, apparently. And yes, I insulted you **in response.**